# A HttpRequest Redirect Exception in UWP Project

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, httpclient

The code goes below

```
public static async Task<string> getForwardUrl(string url)
{
    try
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        HttpRequestMessage forwardRequest = new HttpRequestMessage();

        forwardRequest.RequestUri = new Uri(url);
        HttpResponseMessage Message = await client.SendAsync(forwardRequest);
        return Message.RequestMessage.RequestUri.OriginalString;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
    //...
}
```

When I run this in a `uwp` project, exception occurs. The message of this exception shows that the redirection request would change the safe connection to an unsafe one(After that , I checked the URL of the login page , It's https ,but the page after I logged in is http).

I find a similar question, he recommends using `Windows.Web.Http` instead of `System.Net.Http` but I get the same error message.

Thanks for your reply

EDIT:
The URL is: https://tinyurl.com /57muy (remove the space) or short a **http** url with tinyurl.com! The problem only occurs with a shortet **http** side!
Error: An error occurred while sending the request. Innermessage: Error message not found for this error

Comment: I tested with the url `tinyurl.com/KindleWireless` you've mentioned, however everything works well in my side. There is no error when I using `System.Net.Http` with your code. Could you share a [mcve] that can reproduce your issue?

Comment: With this URL this code work fine, because the target points out a http**s** link. Try it again with **HTTP**. Try it with: 'https://tiny url.com/57muy'

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? It looks like you just want to know the URL, not actually perform a GET request for the data?

Comment: yeah i need only the forwarded url, not the data.

Comment: I'm a little confused with which project you are using. While testing in **UWP**, I can get the same error as you've mentioned. However, you've declared that you are using **WPF**. But in **WPF** there is no error. So what is the project you are really using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, I'd suppose you are developing a UWP app. And as you've mentioned, we got the exception here because the redirection request would change the safe connection to an unsafe one. To solve this problem, we can turn off auto-redirect and do the redirection by ourselves.

For example:

```
public static async Task<string> getForwardUrl(string url)
{
    var handler = new System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler();
    handler.AllowAutoRedirect = false;

    var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient(handler);

    var response = await client.GetAsync(url);

    if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Redirect || response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Moved)
    {
        return response.Headers.Location.AbsoluteUri;
    }

    return url;
}
```